# Setting up multiple traffic manager in WSO2 3.0.0 APIM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

we have an interesting situation, we are using wso2 APIM 3.0.0 in distributed deployment in AWS, and extra gateway and traffic manager in AZURE, What we have realized is, in the publisher store and gateway allows only one traffic manager to configure, we have also gone through wso2 documentation, where there is an option of setting load balancer for multiple traffic managers, can we do the same thing here?

Answer (score 0):

The TM node has 9443 port which is used for deploying throttling policies. i.e When you create a throttling policy in admin portal, that will get deployed in the TM node. From the publisher profile, you will configure this endpoint pointing to the TM node. Atm, we can only configure one entry there. Basically, policy creation is happening less and what you can do is to point to one of the TM and create the policies. THen use the file that gets created in TM profile and copy that to the other TM (Azure). Idea is that you need to have a synching mechanism here to sync execution plans in TM.

Another functionality is throttle data publishing from GW to TM nodes. In this kind of environment if you need to share the throttle data between Azure and AWS, then you need to publish TM data from AWS to Azure and visa versa. Then only TM nodes get updated about the total number of requests that are going via AWS and Azure. In both the environment, you can use expose these TM nodes via an LB. LB should point to one TM node only as we cannot do load balancing in between two TM nodes.